# R: Dynamically passing arguments to pmin or pmax - code not working

Tags: r

The code extract below works fine where Array1 is a populated 3 dimensional array:

```
LotsMaxs <- pmax.int(Array1[,1,],Array1[,2,],Array1[,3,],Array1[,4,])
```

In this example the second dimension which represents treatments (going from 1 to 4 in code above) was knowm to me and hence easy to program. I want to write a function which can handle any number of treatments. So if nTreatment=2 the code above becomes:

```
LotsMaxs <- pmax.int(Array1[,1,],Array1[,2,])
```

I've programmed in commands such as

```
text=noquote(c(paste("Array1[,", 1:(nTreatment-1),",],", sep =   ""),paste("Array1[,", nTreatment,",]", sep = "")))
```

and many variants like it and tried to insert them into commands such as:

```
LotsMaxs <- pmax.int(text) # and:
LotsMaxs <- do.call(pmax.int,list(numeric=text))
```

Nothing I've tried has worked. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Looks like playing with `max.col` will do it... back soon.

Comment: I'd suggest to convert `Array1` into the long format using `melt` command from the `reshape2` package--it will make data processing much easier. For instance, it will be trivial to calculate maxima you looking for with the tools from `dplyr` package.

Comment: A dirty solution (maybe, didn't test): `do.call(pmax.int,lapply(1:nTreatment,function(x) Array1[,x,]))`

Comment: Only now read Nicola's comment - actually better solution than mine. As well as being easier to understand, her's actually runs quicker than mine. In fact although I thought I was being clever vectorising a routine that was much easier to program using a for loop, the reverse is true. My for loop code is actually twice as fast - the hoops I had to go through to vectorise - turning matrices into 3D arrays and messing round with their dimensions wiped out any speed gains.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `apply` for that purpose:

```
apply(Array1, 2, pmax.int)
```

`apply` applies a function (in your case `pmax.int`) to the "MARGIN" of an array.
You want to apply it to the second "MARGIN". See `?apply`

P.S.:
If it is not what you are looking for
please provide a reproduceable example.

Comment: I think he wants only a subset of trhe columns in his array.

Comment: Unfortunately the apply statement gives the wrong answer. This can be seen in the three lines of code below where the correct answer is stored in ans1 which is different from the apply return stored in ans2:

Comment: Unfortunately the apply statement gives the wrong answer.          Array1 <- array(1:24,dim=(2:4)) 
answ1=pmax.int(Array1[,1,],Array1[,2,],Array1[,3,]) #correct
anw2=apply(Array1, 2, pmax.int)  #incorrect. For speed purposes I want to avoid apply/for loop procedures and for similar reasons Hadley's excellent set of routines

Answer (score 2):

I've worked out an answer to my question. Code below

```
nRow=2
nTreatment =3 # column dimension in Array
nDepth = 4 #third dimension in Array
Array1 <- array(1:24,dim=c(nRow,nTreatment,nDepth))
answ1 <- pmax.int(Array1[,1,],Array1[,2,],Array1[,3,]) # this is what I wanted to replicate
DF1 <-data.frame(matrix(aperm(Array1,c(2, 1, 3)),nrow=nRow*nDepth,ncol=nTreatment,byrow=TRUE))
answ2 <- do.call(pmax.int,DF1) # same as answ1
```

Realising that the pmax.int function would use the columns of a dataframe as appropriate arguments in a do.call was my saviour. I realise I might have been able to use eval(parse( call but eval is really slow.  The function I'm writing might be called thousands of times in a simulation hence speed is a priority.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my answer to what I think you're asking.  I use `pickem` to define the columns I want to "feed" to the maximization function.

```
 dput(foo)
structure(c(19L, 3L, 17L, 20L, 2L, 7L, 13L, 16L, 4L, 12L, 11L, 
10L, 18L, 6L, 9L, 24L, 1L, 22L, 8L, 14L, 5L, 21L, 23L, 25L, 15L
), .Dim = c(5L, 5L))
 pickem<-c(1,3,4)
 foo[,pickem]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   19   11   24
[2,]    3   10    1
[3,]   17   18   22
[4,]   20    6    8
[5,]    2    9   14
findmax<-  max.col(foo[,pickem])
[1] 3 2 3 1 3
# compare those row indices with found maxima: 
 pmax.int(foo[,1],foo[,3],foo[,4])
[1] 24 10 22 20 14
```

So what you see is that the output of `max.col` identifies the column which contains the max for each row.  Use those indices, perhaps like

```
 LotsMax <- sapply(1:nrow(foo),function(j) foo[j,findmax[j]])
```

Comment: Good answer to my poorly asked question. I could probably make this work but I wish to avoid any loops (e.g. sapply). I'm timing different solutions to a wider problem and already have a loop solution. I'm seeking a string substituion solution only which I failed to convey. Apologies.